# How to use handlebars inside erb tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, erb, vue.js

I need to submit a form with a hidden field tag that gets its values from my vue instance.

for example:

```
<%= form_for @post, new_data_path %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :data, value: {{ data }} %>
  <%= f.submit 'Checkout' %>
<% end %>
```

Anyway to make handlebars work inside of erb tags?

Comment: your problem is that the double curly braces conflict with the Vue syntax? please explain a litle more

Comment: yeah if I do something like `<input value="{{ data }}"></input>` then that will display with no problems but any handlebar syntax won't work inside erb tags. I get `syntax error, unexpected '}',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue seems to be evaluated before the handlebar rendering. Use Vue [delimiters](http://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters) to change the default `{{}}`

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['@{', '}']
```

So now your double curly braces are ignored by Vue.

Comment: so would I put that in my vue.js file and replace the 2 curly backets with whatever I want?

Comment: In your main Vue file, and replace double braces where you want vue code, and keep them where you want handlebar

Comment: IMO, is better to have separated Vue code from rails variables. I did some time ago a litle template using [Vuejs and rails](https://github.com/YerkoPalma/vuejs-rails), I passed every rails variable from the controller to rails, and wrap the template in a `script` tag, so I actually never faced this problem. Check the repo, I think is a good approach because it doen´t mix erb syntax with vue syntax

Answer (score 1):

you just need to wrap {{ data }} in quotes and it works.